# How does Jenkins deal with python scripts with Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, popen

We use Jenkins to run our cronjobs.  We run Centos 6.8 on our server.  Jenkins is version 1.651.

I'm running into a funny problem.  When I run my script from the terminal, it works fine.  I don't get any errors.

When I run the same script in Jenkins, it fails and says there's no such file or directory.

The error message from the Jenkins output I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runMTTRScript.py", line 256, in <module>
    main()
  File "runMTTRScript.py", line 252, in main
    startTest(start, end, impalaHost)
  File "runMTTRScript.py", line 72, in startTest
    getResults(start, end)
  File "runMTTRScript.py", line 111, in getResults
    proc1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=processlistOut)
  File "/glide/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/glide/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here's the code that the error above is complaining about:

```
   with open(JAVAOUT + "_processList" + outfileDate, 'w') as processlistOut, \
      open(JAVAOUT + "_innodb" + outfileDate, 'w') as innodbOut:
      cmd = ["java", "-cp", "MTTR4hrs-1.0.5-SNAPSHOT-allinone.jar", "com.servicenow.bigdata.MTTR4hrs", "-c", "config.properties", "-m", DBIFILE, "-d", start, end, "-f", "processlist", "-ds", "dbi"]
      proc1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=processlistOut)

      cmd = ["java", "-cp", "MTTR4hrs-1.0.5-SNAPSHOT-allinone.jar", "com.servicenow.bigdata.MTTR4hrs", "-c", "config.properties", "-m", DBIFILE, "-d", start, end, "-f", "engineinnodbstatus", "-ds", "dbi"]
      proc2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=innodbOut)
```

Why would it complain that a file is not there from Jenkins but be fine when I run it from cmd line?  Could this also be some race condition in python that I'm not aware of too?  The "with...open" doesn't open a file fast enough for the Popen to make use of?  I'm also open to the fact that it might be some OS problem too (too many open files, something stupid, etc.).

Comment: What is your `$JAVA_HOME` set to in Jenkins? It's not finding that jar..

Comment: Also, absolute classpath >> relative classpath, for this exact reason and others

Comment: @NoticeMeSenpai, thx for your interest in my quesiton.  I don't think it's a path problem.  I think it's an OS problem.  I just installed Jenkins on another server (less busy server) and the job and script works fine.  =(